# How to profile Nuxt.js (SSR) application?

Tags: nuxt.js

I would like to profile nuxt.js (SSR) application. Do you know profiling tool in order to profile nuxt.js?

Comment: What do you mean by profile? Which aspect?

Comment: how long does it take to fetch data in components and pages.
how long does it take to process js
how long does it take to render. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

There is no Nuxt dedicated tool for profiling. You can use the "Performance" tab of the Vue devtools.

Or your integrated browser profiling/performance tab. Here is an example for Chrome: https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/02/20/effective-profiling-in-google-chrome.html

Not sure for Node, but there should be some packages too (for the SSR part), googling it should provide some nice ones.

Id you want to analyze the bundle size, this one can be helpful for Webpack: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer